# docker error during connect - deamon is not running on Windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-10, hyper-v, docker-engine

I am using Windows 10 pc. Recently I have downloaded docker for Windows and it was working fine. But, recently a problem occurred and is it not start anymore it just hang in the status starting.

I haven't changed any configuration and I am wondering what may cause this problem.

I use the latest version of docker.

[image]

On my pc, Hyper-V is enabled and Containers are disabled. (Since, I son't use Windows container, I don't think it is necessary. )

[image]

On task bar, when I check docker icon. It is always in starting status.

[image]

When I check services, it seems it is running.

[image]

when I try docker command on powershell. It could not found docker command.

I am not in an urgency to set up docker, I was just playing with it. But, suddenly this problem occured. I have been trying to solve this problem for a while. I have search similar problems and uninstall docker several times while searching for a solution. It is wierd and disturbing that a tool suddenly stop working and there is no trace to find the root problem. I suspect may be company sucurity policy change effects my computer and cause this problem But I could not find any clue to support this.

My question is what should I do to understand what is wrong. What cause the problem and how can it be fixed.

Note: When I restart computer following error occurs.

[image]

content of the error message:

> error during connect: Get
>   http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.30/containers/json: open
>   //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In
>   the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be
>   run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker
>   daemon is not running.
>
> at Docker.Backend.DockerDaemonChecker.Check(Func`1
>   isDaemonProcessStillRunning) in
>   C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\DockerDaemonChecker.cs:line
>   63    at
>   Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0(Object[]
>   parameters) in
>   C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeServer.cs:line
>   47    at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.RunAction(String action,
>   Object[] parameters) in
>   C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeServer.cs:line
>   145

When I run `docker ps -a` following error occurs.

> docker ps -a error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.30/containers/json?all=1:
>   open //./pipe/docker_engine : The system cannot find the file
>   specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker
>   client must be r un elevated to connect. This error may also indicate
>   that the docker daemon is not running.

Comment: Open Hyper-V and delete the docker VM and reinstall Docker for windows

Comment: Although I had already install docker, There is no listed virtual machine on Hyper-V manager. "No virtual machines were found on this server." But, I am using Linux containers, not Windows containers. Maybe, it is related to that.

Comment: If you have linux containers then the VM needs to be there, else it won't work. And that may be the issue, because there is no backing VM so docker cannot work. Not sure why the VM was not instantiated at all

Comment: I am facing exactly similar issue in Windows 10. Did you find any solution ?

Comment: yes, problem resolved. check hyper-v installed. check hyper-v and container features are enabled. check docker service is running. and make sure you use you use the latest docker. Also, you can open a ticket on https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues, if you upload logs, they will help you. In my case, problem resolved with docker update to new version. (Actually it was already latest but a new one released and it fixed the issue. So probably it was a docker bug.) Be patient, keep trying :) let me know if it is resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the security permissions on the docker.exe to include users and restart your PC. This should fix it.

[image]

Comment: It didn't help. Also new versions of Docker does not include "Docker for Windows" executable

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause I can think of is that a given PowerShell instance won't "know about" things that didn't exist when it was first launched.  Have you tried starting opening a new PowerShell window *after* installing Docker?

EDIT: Well, sounds like that's not the issue.  Does a regular cmd shell recognize the Docker commands?

Comment: yes, I even restart computer. Also, I have reinstall docker a few times :)

Comment: I am facing exactly similar issue in Windows 10. Any solution ?