# What is the difference between docker deamon and Docker for Windors service

Tags: unix, docker, windows-services, daemon

Since Windows is not a Unix based operating system, I thought there is no concept such as deamon and instead there are Windows services.

Lately, I have a problem using Docker on Windows and I am trying to make troubleshooting. I have opend a ticket for the issue: [docker issues](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1054)

It seems Docker for Windows service is working properly. 
[image]

But, When I run docker deamon, I get an error message.

```
> dockerd
dockerd : The term 'dockerd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Che
ck the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ dockerd
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (dockerd:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I assume Windows service is a concept for deamons in wondows, so is docker service is running, docker deamon should respond.

Is my assumption correct? Is ther any difference between docker deamon and docker service for Windows?

Comment: A daemon or a service in Windows refer to a background process. In other words, these processes exist solely to perform some tasks behind the scenes when some events take place. [_"On the Microsoft Windows operating systems, programs called services perform the functions of daemons, although the term daemon is now sometimes being used with regard to those systems as well."_](http://www.linfo.org/daemon.html).

Comment: Did you try docker command? dockerd is no more used for daemon

Comment: @TarunLalwani yes I have tried. But, another error occurs when run docker command. thats what I try to solve. I have asked another question about it. you can check it out from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45824910/docker-error-during-connect-deamon-is-not-running-on-windows-10